# Laptop won't follow an editing step in a tutorial I am doing

Tags: modeling

I am following a [basic doughnut tutorial](https://youtu.be/RaT-uG5wgUw) that I am doing on my laptop.

At some point, the guy in the video says while you have proportional editing mode on and have pressed the g key, 'scroll up or down' until a round circle appears that you use to model your shape with. However, When I try this, my laptop doesn't work.

I have emulated my middle mouse button and I am holding alt + left click while scrolling. Does anyone have any idea what is going on and what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: use page up and down to change proportional editing size when emulate middle mouse button is on (shift + page up/down to be more accurate) .

Comment: I do not use a mouse then I scroll it using page up and page down.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to hold down any mouse click to scroll or change the size of the proportional editing circle. Emulating middle mouse emulates a middle mouse CLICK (ie pressing the mouse wheel down like a button).

In proportional editing, begin the editing command (whatever it is, move, scale, rotate, etc.) then you are free to scroll to make the proportional editing circle larger or smaller by simply scrolling, usually 2 fingers up or down on the trackpad.

you can also use Page Up & Down, but some laptops won't have that.

Answer (score 0):

First: when doing any 3D work, you **must** have a mouse. With a trackpad you are 5 times slower and some things will probably not work

Second: check that proportional editing is actually turned on (it's the button with the circles in the top bar)

[image]

Third: while moving your vertices, check in the top left corner the *Proportional size*: it should be a reasonable number. If it's hundreds of thousands or a a fraction of a millimeter, scroll up/down to fix it

[image]

Comment: Totally disagree about "With a trackpad you are 5 times slower".

Comment: I guess that with a bit of practise you can do it faster, but a mouse is by far the best solution, and even if you are on the go, a light, small and cheap one is still better than the trackpad IMO

Comment: Well, this is not a debate subject, but the reason is simple: with a touchpad, all your fingers stay closer to both touchpad and keyboard. That's why this is faster in my opinion.